# canvas scale also translates the shape unexpectedly possible pivot anchor related issue

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

When I draw a rectangle with a scale it translates to unexpected locations. What I want is to rectangle to stay at the same x y position while getting bigger.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      document.body.append(canvas);
      
const width = canvas.clientWidth,
      height = canvas.clientHeight;
      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
      
const $range = document.getElementById('scale');
$range.oninput = function() {
  const value = this.value;
  
  draw(ctx, value);
}
      
function draw(ctx, scale) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.scale(1.0, scale);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 10, 10);
  ctx.restore();
}

function assets(link) {
  const img = new Image();
  const res = new Promise(resolve => {
  img.onload = () => {
    resolve(img);
  }
  });
  img.src = link;
  return res;
}

assets('https://via.placeholder.com/150').then(image => {
  draw(ctx, image);
})
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span>scale</span>
<input type='range' min="0" max="10" value="1" id="scale"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**

The reason your rectangle moves unexpectedly is that you are giving a static `y` position for your rectangle while you are scaling your canvas by `scale` factor. So to keep your rectangle in the same `y` position you have to divide the rectangle's `y` property by `scale` factor. Check the code I changed it for you :)
I didn't change the `x` property because you scaled your canvas like `(1, scale)` So the `x` would remain the same.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
document.body.append(canvas);

const width = canvas.clientWidth,
  height = canvas.clientHeight;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;


draw(ctx, 1);

const $range = document.getElementById('scale');
$range.oninput = function() {
  const value = this.value;

  draw(ctx, value);
}

function draw(ctx, scale) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.scale(1.0, scale);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillRect(50, 50 / scale, 10, 10);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>scale</span>
  <input type='range' min="0" max="10" value="1" id="scale" />
</div>
```

**Solution 2**

Another solution for your Scaling problem could be using `translate` function. First you translate your origin to the point where you want your rectangle to be drawn from, in your example `(50, 50)` , then you do your `scale()` and after that you can draw your rectangle from your new origin, and because you have moved your origin to `(50, 50)` you can draw your rectangle like `ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);` and at the end simply `translate` back to `(0, 0)` as your default origin.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
document.body.append(canvas);

const width = canvas.clientWidth,
  height = canvas.clientHeight;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

draw(ctx, 1);

const $range = document.getElementById('scale');
$range.oninput = function() {
  const value = this.value;

  draw(ctx, value);
}

function draw(ctx, scale) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(50, 50);
  ctx.scale(1.0, scale);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
  ctx.translate(0, 0);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>scale</span>
  <input type='range' min="0" max="10" value="1" id="scale" />
</div>
```

**Concerning rotate around center**

And for Rotating a shape around it's center in canvas, first you have to `translate` to center of that shape, then `rotate`, then `translate` back to `(0, 0)`

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var x = 40;
var y = 40;
var width = 80;
var height = 80
var cx = x + 0.5 * width; // x of shape center
var cy = y + 0.5 * height; // y of shape center

draw(context, 0);

const $range = document.getElementById('rotate');
$range.oninput = function() {
  const value = this.value;

  draw(context, value);
}

function draw(ctx, rotateScale) {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width * 2, height * 2);
  context.save();

  context.translate(cx, cy); //translate to center of shape
  context.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * rotateScale); //rotate rotateScale degrees.
  context.translate(-cx, -cy); //translate center back to 0,0

  context.fillStyle = "#0000ff";
  context.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

  context.restore();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<br/>
<input type='range' min="0" max="360" value="1" id="rotate" />
```

Comment: but why, i don't want to change the y, i want scaling to work out of blue.

Comment: When you scale the whole canvas, It's like you are looking at it through a magnifier, everything gets bigger or smaller :) assume that pixels get bigger, so a point in(50, 50) after scaling by 2, goes to (100, 100)

Comment: I think I see your point, what about I want to rotate around the origin of the shape?

Comment: Check this link, , The visuals help you a lot   -   https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_scale2

Comment: Rotating is totally different case. All you need is to find the center of the shape, or any other origin you desire and call rotate function. and if you want to scale and rotate at the same time, you have to calculate new rotate origin after scaling then call rotate()

Comment: can you extend your answer to do a rotation around center instead of a scaling

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198684/discussion-between-eguneys-and-masoudmanson).